# Route [admin.distroyDish] not defined. (View: /home/abdalrazag/MyResutrant/resources/views/admin/manager.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 to build Restaurant system
I made form that go to specific route
and I get name route but it is display error as the title

manager view

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('admin.distroyDish')}}" >
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="dish">
    @for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($InetialData['dish']); $i++))
    <option value="{{ $InetialData['dish'][$i]->id }}">
        {{ $InetialData['dish'][$i]->name }}
    </option>
    @endfor
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="delete_dish" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
    <br>
</form>
```

web Route file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/manager', 'ManagerController@dashboard');
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@addItem');
Route::get('/manager/{id}', 'ManagerController@deleteTable')->name('admin.deleteTable');
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@destroyDish')->name('admin.distroyDish');
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@addIngrediant')->name('admin.addIngrediant');
Route::get('/kitchen', 'KitchenController@index')->name('kitchen.home');
Route::get('/kitchen/{id}', 'KitchenController@submitDish')->name('kitchen.submit.dish');
Route::post('/kitchen', 'KitchenController@addIngrediant')->name('kitchen.addIngrediant');
```

ManagerController

```
private function initData()
{
    $InetialData = array(
        'category' => DB::table('Category')->get(),
        'dish' => DB::table('Items')->get(),
        'users' => DB::table('users')->get(),
        'Ingrediant' => DB::table('Ingrediant')->get(),
        'IngrediantHistory' => DB::table('IngrediantHistory')->get()
    );

    return $InetialData;
}

public function destroyDish(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('Items')
        ->where('id', '=', $request->dish)
        ->delete();

    return redirect('/manager')->with('InetialData' , $this->initData());
}
```

other route like kitchen is working
why this route is not working ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got duplicate routes:

```
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@addItem');
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@destroyDish')->name('admin.distroyDish');
Route::post('/manager', 'ManagerController@addIngrediant')->name('admin.addIngrediant');
```

Change the endpoint structure.

Comment: do you mean url should unique even the name route is differant ?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have more routes calling POST /manager. Try to use routes like resources:

1. GET    /entities            **list**
2. GET    /entities/{entity}   **view**
3. POST   /entities            **create**
4. PUT    /entities/{entity}   **update**
5. DELETE /entities/{entity}   **delete**

Elegant and easy to mantain and read.